# Inserting relative function VBA with references to variables

Tags: excel, vba

Say that I want to insert a relative formula that sums range. One of the rows' value is determined by an integer.

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 5
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[i+5]C)"
```

The above does not work. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[" & i+5 & "]C)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
rng.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[1]C:R[" & i+5 & "]C)"
```

Assuming that is what you are trying to do. The formula is a string, so in order to insert your variable (i) into the string, you need to exit it, and include your variable, then re-enter the string by using double quotes and ampersands.